# How can I hide the the page scrollbar on MUI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, scrollbar, hide

I need to know how to hide it on the page. I tried searching for it but couldn't find a solution for MUI.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `hidden` property to `overflow`. Like,

`style={{ overflow: "hidden" }}`